# codename one : fixed button while scrolling

Tags: java, button, codenameone

i want to create a button that is fixed while scrolling in my form it's an add button

is it possible to make a fixed button when scrolling in a page in codename one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are a lot of ways to do that. In this case the simplest thing is a `FloatingActionButton` so something like this should work fine:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD);
fab.bindFabToContainer(myForm);
fab.addActionListener(e -> doThisWhenClicked());
```

Comment: Maybe for an "Add" button the FAB (FloatingActionButton) is the best option (as Shai suggested). Other solutions can be obtained using appropriate Containers and Layouts, for example you can have a page scrollable in Center of a BorderLayout and a fixed Button in the South of the BorderLayout.